# Cannot precompile assets for production environment, Rails 4.2.1, bower components

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, bower, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am using bower for third parties on front-end.

I have problem with iCheck component which is used in AdminLTE theme.

Here is application.sass file of my Ruby on Rails 4.2.1 server side app:

```
@import "bootstrap-css-only/css/bootstrap"
@import "css/AdminLTE"
@import "css/skin-purple"

/*theme AdminLTE-2.3.0*/
@import "font-awesome/css/font-awesome"
@import "iCheck/skins/minimal/_all"
@import "iCheck/skins/square/_all"
@import "iCheck/skins/flat/_all"
@import "iCheck/skins/line/_all"
@import "iCheck/skins/polaris/polaris"
@import "iCheck/skins/futurico/futurico"
@import "iCheck/skins/all"

/*javascript notifications*/
@import "pnotify/src/pnotify.core"
@import "pnotify/src/pnotify.buttons"

/* Font awesome import*/
@import "font-awesome/css/font-awesome"

/*angular modules stylesheets*/
@import "core/stylesheets/users"
```

There is a problem with iCheck component because in file iCheck/skins/all.css there are imports:

```
@import url("minimal/_all.css");
@import url("square/_all.css");
```

And when I precompile assets for production environment, those css files do not exist. In development mode, everything works like a charm!

Any suggestion on this?

Comment: What is the error you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that your compiled css file still has the same import commands, which is referencing the `minimal/_all.css` and `square/_all.css`.

There are two solutions for this problem:

1. You could change the extension of all imported files to `scss`, and change the import directive from `@import url("...")` to `@import "..."`
2. Or you could copy the files, which are imported with url to your public folder, and your browser will find them (of course, they will not be minified, and i would not suggest you do use this solution)

Comment: It didn't helped. I still have same problems. BTW, I am starting server in production environment, also I am compiling assets with RAILS_ENV=production. I am not deploying code. Just preparing app for deployment.

Comment: @cricket42: i see, then my answer is absolutely wrong. I will fix it

Comment: @cricket42: fixed my answer, hope it helps.

Comment: @Yuri Lebedev Still having same problems

Comment: @Yuri Lebedev It worked after removing .css from import argument.

Comment: @cricket42 yep, I forgot to mention this